# Where do I place "doOnError" in my webclient call?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient

I have a webclient call that looks like :-

```
return this.webClient.post()
                .uri(url)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Reponse.class)
                .doOnError(err -> {
                    throw new UserDefinedException();
                })
                .block();
```

Would it make a difference if i placed "doOnError()" before bodyToMono/retreive/ and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected way to transform an error signal to a custom exception is to use `onErrorMap` operator:

```java
return this.webClient.post()
                .uri(url)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Reponse.class)
                .onErrorMap(err -> new UserDefinedException())
                .block();
```

`onErrorMap` operator catch any `Mono` errors and map them to a custom exception.

`bodyToMono`, transform the chain to a `Mono` in the success case, so it could be after `onErrorMap`.

Comment: So in your example above, will onErrorMap catch errors  from retrieve() as well ?

Comment: @user1354825 yes.